# Is it possible that contain additional information on multidimensional array?

Tags: c#, arrays

for example:

the school has two groups and also each group has 5 children.

`int[][] groups = new  int[2,5]` The array shows age of corresponding student

`groups[1,1] = 12` this is First student of first group, "he is 12 years old" and "his name is Alex". Like this can i contain( or call) additional information?

`groups[2,1] = 11`  1st student of 2nd class. ...

Comment: Create a `Student` class.

Comment: Instead of making the array an 'int' create a class with an 'int' and the additional info.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with it being an array. You're basically asking whether `int` can store anything other than the number: no, it can't.

Comment: We typically don't use multi dimensional arrays in real world C#. We create classes that represent the data we need, and then instances of that class can be placed in an array (or more commonly a `List<T>`).

Comment: Sure it can just store a number but to be honest a number can hold much more info. Map info in binary where the first 7 equals age 8th gender etc. Not very feasible and very limited but still :) @Jon Skeet

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understand that comment at all...

Comment: @JonSkeet I think he's saying that you could for example use different bit masks to store/retrieve different data from a single int value. For example, an 8-bit number in the first 8 bits, a bit flag for the gender in the 9th bit (for example) and so on..

Answer (score 5):

> [I]s it possible that store additional information on array elements?

Not if the type is an `int[][]`. What you can do however is **define a class**. Like:

```
public class Child {

    private string name;
    private int age;

    public Child(string name, int age) { // constructor
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

and then you can declare a 2d `Person` array, like:

```
Child[,] groups = new Child[2,5];
groups[0,0] = new Child("Alex",12);
```

The second statement invokes the *constructor* and creates a new `Child` object.

Additional remarks:

- by default indices have **zero-offset**. So assigning to `groups[2,1]` is not possible; and
- an `int[][]` is something **different than `int[,]`**.

Comment: thanks. And also, if i am working with large data, i will use their numbers(age) on test criteria, Is it okay to call each class?

Comment: @TomooMGL: what do you mean with *call each class*?

Comment: well i mean, Is it take long time? isn't it.

Comment: @TomooMGL: well it will take a bit longer than working with `int`s since it will allocate on a heap, etc. But since your array contains 2x5=10 elements, that's not an issue. Only if you would process 100M+ elements, performance can be an issue.